# Comparing two dataframes with some entries missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I want to compare like:

df1

```
   name | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
0 |  A  |    2    |   NaN   |    2
1 |  B  |    3    |    1    |   NaN
2 |  C  |    5    |    2    |    1
```

df2

```
   name | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
0 |  A  |   NaN   |   NaN   |    2
1 |  B  |    2    |    1    |    0
2 |  C  |    5    |    3    |    1
```

An ideal comparison result df would look like:

```
   name |   value_1   |   value_2   |    value_3
0 |  A  |   missing2  |   missing   |     True
1 |  B  |    False    |     True    |    missing1
2 |  C  |     True    |    False    |     True
```

This is what I did (but failed):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 2, np.nan, 2],
    ['B', 3, 1, np.nan],
    ['C', 5, 2, 1],
], columns=['name', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', np.nan, np.nan, 2],
    ['B', 2, 1, 0],
    ['C', 5, 3, 1],
], columns=['name', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'])

df = df1 == df2
df[['name']] = df1[['name']]

df[df1.isnull()] = "missing1"
df[df2.isnull()] = "missing2"
df[df1.isnull() & df2.isnull()] = "missing"
```

I received the following error message when doing `df[df1.isnull()] = "missing1"`:

> TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Does anyone have any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: The error means you can only set `df[df1.isnull()] = np.nan` instead of a string value here.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom is there anyway I can produce the desired comparison result dataframe?

Comment: Why do you have to set the missing value as a string considering the result data frame contain boolean types ? Isn't it more natural to use `np.nan` here ?

Comment: With that said, I think if you move `name` column as index so `df` is no longer mixed types, your assignment will work.

Comment: @Psidom This is because I want to label in the result in which dataframe the value is missing

Comment: @Psidom Thanks a lot that works! Could you make it answer so I can accept it (if you'd like to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't assign a string value when there are mixed types in the data frame. One workaround is to convert the boolean result data frame to string before assigning `missing` labels:

```
df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name', inplace=True)

df = (df1 == df2).astype(str)

df[df1.isnull()] = "missing1"
df[df2.isnull()] = "missing2"
df[df1.isnull() & df2.isnull()] = "missing"

df
       value_1  value_2   value_3
name                             
A     missing2  missing      True
B        False     True  missing1
C         True    False      True
```